# Logitech Mouse and Keyboard freezing on Ubuntu 20.04 with Dell XPS 15 9570

Tags: 20.04, freeze, logitech

I have been using for a number of years without issue, but recently bought a Dell XPS 15 9570 that's driving me nuts because of an issue I am having with the Logitech mouse and keyboard that I use with it (both are connected through the same unifying receiver).  I am intermittently having issues where both keyboard and mouse "freeze" for 1 - 6 seconds.  The onboard keyboard and trackpad work fine at the same time though.

I'm struggling to pinpoint the issue, and am honestly not sure about how best to troubleshoot this.

Been running the following, and don't see an obvious issue at the time when it happens:

```
tail -f /var/log/{messages,kernel,dmesg,syslog} | tee ~/mouse-freezing.log
```

Can anyone suggest the best way to go about troubleshooting this, any steps I could take to try and fix this, or what logs are best to analyse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was fixed by disabling autosuspend for the USB device.  It was a power-related issue.  Fixed with `tlp`:

find the offending USB device id:

```
lsusb
```

Blacklist the device with `USB_BLACKLIST` in a config file under  `/etc/tlp.d/`

```
sudo vi /etc/tlp.d/50-usb-autosuspend-blacklist.conf
```

Add the following, replacing for your USB ID(s):

```
USB_BLACKLIST="YYYY:YYYY XXXX:XXXX"
```

Restart `tlp` to have it take immediate effect:

```
sudo systemctl restart tlp
```

**Source:**

https://newbedev.com/how-to-disable-auto-power-off-of-usb-devices-like-usb-mouse